# Add item to cart if size property is different but the ID keys are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, cart, shopping-cart

I created a cart push insert items into it, the logic is this:

I have an array:

```
`let cartItems = [];`
```

To contain Product objects with defined properties:

```
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Nike Hoodie 1",
 ...
}
```

I would like to increase an item's `quantity` property and set size property (if the item exists in the array) any time I push a new item to the `cartItems` array. However, if the value of `productSize` of the new item is different from the existing item's `productSize` property, I would like to push this new item to the `cartItems` array with `quantity: 1` rather than increasing the `quantity as I described earlier.

But the problem with `id` property appears because the id is the same for both products. And when I try to remove or update `cartItems` array, this would throw an error because I use the `id` property of the products to find and map the `cartItems` array. Please help?

I have tried to create a `temporaryId` property set to a random number for each product but I don't know how work this solution. This is the code I wrote:

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd, selectedSize) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
    (cartItem) => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
  );
  if (existingCartItem) {
    if (existingCartItem.productSize === selectedSize) {
      console.log('product sizes are the same');
      return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
          ? {
              ...cartItem,
              quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1,
            }
          : cartItem
      );
    } else {
      console.log('product sizes are not the same');
      return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
          ? {
              ...cartItem,
              quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1,
              productSize: selectedSize,
            }
          : cartItem
      );
    }
  }
  let randomId = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  return [
    ...cartItems,
    {
      ...cartItemToAdd,
      tempId: randomId,
      quantity: 1,
      productSize: selectedSize,
    },
  ];
};
```

Comment: You can use `const item = cartItems.find(item => item.id === searchId)`. If `item` isn't null, just increase `item.quantity`. If it's null, push a new element.

Comment: and then if the user then wants to change the quantity of a cart item how will you/they know if they've removed the one with the size large vs the size medium? Maybe you do need to actually show both in some way vs increment a quantity

Comment: @ChrisG - yes but when the item comes first it has no searchId as property, i can not understand your idea very well.

Comment: @Kinglish - If the product we are adding is the same as the one in the cart items array but it does not have the same product size I want to insert it as a new product (separately) and not increase quantity.

Comment: It's just example code. I didn't read about the size issue though, but this just means that you have to amend the find function: `item => item.id === cartItemToAdd.id && item.size === cartItemToAdd.size`

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @ChrisG.  My solution below handles being able to check id AND size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to do it is to modify your `existingCartItem` check.  Instead of finding the item with that `id`, find the index of the item that matches `id` AND `productSize`.

```
 const existingCartItemIndex = cartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => {
     return cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id && cartItem.productSize === selectedSize;
  });
});
```

That way, if the index is > -1 you know the index of the item you need to modify, otherwise you know you need to add the item to the array.

So, a solution would look like this:

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd, selectedSize) => {
  const existingCartItemIndex = cartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => {
     return cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id && cartItem.productSize === selectedSize;
  });

  if (existingCartItemIndex > -1) {
     cartItems[existingCartItemIndex].quantity = cartItems[existingCartItemIndex].quantity + 1;
  } else {
    cartItems.push({ 
      ...cartItemToAdd, 
      quantity: 1, 
      productSize: selectedSize
  }

  return cartItems;
};
```

Hope this helps!